# Best way to handle missing :include option in ActiveRecord4 Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm Trying to see what it would take to update our project to Rails 4.

Right now I'm stuck because a lot of our associations use the include option.

```
has_many   :foos, :include => :bar
```

According to the documentation in `ActiveRecord 3.2`

```
:include
    Specify second-order associations that should be eager loaded when this object is loaded.
```

I see it's completely gone in `ActiveRecord 4`.

I didn't find an upgrade guide and am wondering what is the best approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually still possible, but in Rails 4, you need to pass a lambda:

```
has_many :foos, -> { includes :bar }
```